# Ruby on Rails with sqlite, trying to query and return results from the last 7 days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Noob here, I'm trying to query my SQLite database for entries that have been made in the last 7 days and then return them.
This is the current attempt

user.rb

```
def featuredfeed
      @x = []
      @s = []

      Recipe.all.each do |y|
        @x << "SELECT id FROM recipes WHERE id = #{y.id} AND created_at > datetime('now','-7 days')"
      end

      Recipe.all.each do |d|
        @t = "SELECT id FROM recipes where id = #{d.id}"
        @x.each do |p|
          if @t = p
            @s << d
          end
        end

      end
      @s          
  end
```

This code returns each recipe 6(total number of objects in the DB) times regardless of how old it is.

@x should only be 3 id's

```
@x = [13,15,16]
```

if i run

```
SELECT id FROM recipes WHERE id = 13 AND created_at > datetime('now','-7 days')
```

1 Rows returned with id 13 is returned

but if look for an id that is more than 7 days old such as 12

```
SELECT id FROM recipes WHERE id = 12 AND created_at > datetime('now','-7 days')
```

0 Rows returned

I'm probably over complicating this but I've spent way too long on it at this point.

the return type has to be Recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return objects created within last 7 days just use where clause:

```
Recipe.where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago)
```

[Check out docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) for more info on querying db.

## Edit according to comments:

Since you are using [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#caching) gem, add the votes caching, so that filtering by votes score is straightforward:

```
Recipe.where('cached_votes_total >= ?', 10)
```

Comment: Except use >= not < since you want items created in the last week

Comment: np I tried to make the edit but it was only a single character so it wouldn't let me :)

Comment: They allow to make such edits later, with like 2.5k or 5k rep, do not remember exactly :)

Comment: Thanks that worked. only thing is i now want to ask that the recipes returned votes are greater than X ammount

i.e.
select count() from votes where votable_id = #{@current_recipe_id}) > 10

Comment: Recipe.joins(:votes).where('count(votes.id) > 10')
this returns an error Association named 'votes' was not found on Recipe
Recipe uses the acts_as_votable gem

Comment: @user2482038 Since you are using acts_as_votable gem, getting a count of all votes is straightforward:
`Recipe.where('cached_votes_total >= ?', 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is expressive.  I would take the opportunity to use a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope).  With Active Record Scopes, this query can be represented in a meaningful way within your code, using syntactic sugar.

```
scope :from_recent_week, -> { where('created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now - 1.week) }
```

This allows you to chain your scoped query and enhance readability:

```
Recipe.from_recent_week.each do
  something_more_meaningful_than_a_SQL_query
end
```

It looks to me that your problem is database abstraction, something Rails does for you.  If you are looking for a function that returns the three ids you indicate, I think you would want to do this:

```
@x = Recipe.from_recent_week.map(&:id)
```

No need for any of the other fluff, no declarations necessary.  I also would encourage you to use a different variable name instead of @x.  Please use something more like:

```
@ids_from_recent_week = Recipe.from_recent_week.map(&:id)
```